# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of null at Context.<anonymous> in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I try to use the **toArray** function a newly creates list I keep getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of null at Context".

I'm trying to create a linked list implementation. the **toArray** function must not change but I'm pretty sure the problem has to be in the **reduce** function, if not that then maybe the **fromArray** function

```
type Selector<T> = (head:T, rest?:Cons<T>)=> T|Cons<T>;
type Cons<T> = (selector: Selector<T>) => T|Cons<T>;

function cons<T>(head:T, rest?: Cons<T>): Cons<T> {
    return (selector: Selector<T>) => selector(head, rest);
}

function head<T>(list:Cons<T>):T {
    return <T>list((head, rest?) => head);
}

function rest<T>(list:Cons<T>):Cons<T> {
    return <Cons<T>>list((head, rest?) => rest);
}

function fromArray<T>(arr:T[]):Cons<T>{
    function aux(array:T[], i:number):Cons<T>{
        if(i<array.length){
            return cons(array[i], aux(array.slice(i+1), i))
        }
        else{
            return null
        }
    }
    return aux(arr, 0);
}

function reduce<T>(f:(x:T, y:T)=>T, initial:T, list:any):T {
    if(list){
        return reduce(f, f(initial, head(list)), rest(list));
    }
    else{
        return initial;
    }
}

class List<T> {
    private head: Cons<T>;

    constructor(list: T[] | Cons<T>) {
        if (list instanceof Array) {        
            this.head = fromArray(list);
        } else {
            this.head = list;
        }
    }

    toArray(): T[] {
        return reduce((a,t)=>(a.push(t), a), [], this.head).reverse();
    }
```

Comment: How do you call this method? Could you recreate the issue https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html? With small correction your reduce function typechecks and works.

Answer (score 1):

You should turn on the `strictNullChecks` compiler option, since there's a lot of `undefined` and `null` floating around your code without flagging any errors.  The main issue here is that in your implementation, the empty list is simply `undefined` (or maybe `null`), and you're not checking for it in enough places.  The following is what I debugged into being; I don't know if all the bugs are gone, but `toArray()` seems to work now.  I added some comments where I changed things:

```
type Selector<T> = (head: T, rest?: Cons<T>) => T | Cons<T>;
// a list can be undefined, so I added it:
type Cons<T> = undefined | ((selector: Selector<T>) => T | Cons<T>);

function cons<T>(head: T, rest?: Cons<T>): Cons<T> {
  return (selector: Selector<T>) => selector(head, rest);
}

// the head function is guaranteed to return a T only on a non-empty list,
// so I overloaded it:
function head(list: undefined): undefined;
function head<T>(list: Cons<T>): T;
function head<T>(list: Cons<T>): T | undefined {
  if (!list) return; // watch out for empty list
  return <T>list((head, rest?) => head);
}

function rest<T>(list: Cons<T>): Cons<T> {
  if (!list) return; // watch out for empty list
  return <Cons<T>>list((head, rest?) => rest);
}

function fromArray<T>(arr: T[]): Cons<T> {
  function aux(array: T[], i: number): Cons<T> {
    if (i < array.length) {
      return cons(array[i], aux(array.slice(i + 1), i))
    }
    else {
      return; // use undefined instead of null, easier this way
    }
  }
  return aux(arr, 0);
}

// note that you want reduce to return a T[] instead of a T in toArray()
// that means your f cannot be (x:T, y:T) => T.  Add a U parameter for the
// type of initial, return value, and the return type of f
function reduce<T, U>(f: (x: U, y: T) => U, initial: U, list: Cons<T>): U {
  if (list) {
    return reduce(f, f(initial, head(list)), rest(list));
  }
  else {
    return initial;
  }
}

class List<T> {
  private head: Cons<T>;

  constructor(list: T[] | Cons<T>) {
    if (list instanceof Array) {
      this.head = fromArray(list);
    } else {
      this.head = list;
    }
  }

  toArray(): T[] {
    // push puts things at the end; you're trying to cons, right?  
    // that's unshift
    return reduce<T, T[]>((a, t) => (a.unshift(t), a), [], this.head).reverse();
  }
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!